# Abstract connectedness

Tags: gn.general-topology

Is there an abstract structure that characterizes connectedness, analogously to how topological spaces characterize continuity?

Here's one way to make this question more precise: if $(X,T_X)$ is a topological space with underlying set $X$ and topology $T_X$, then consider the pair $(X,C_X)$ where $C_X$ is the set of connected subsets of $X$.  A continuous map $f:(X,T_X) \to (Y,T_Y)$ has the property that the direct image of a connected set is connected.  Thus, we have a functor from **Top** to the category whose objects are pairs $(X,C_X)$ of a set equipped with a set of subsets, and whose maps $f:(X,C_X)\to (Y,C_Y)$ are functions $f:X\to Y$ such that $f(U) \in C_Y$ for all $U\in C_X$.  Is there a naturally defined full subcategory of the latter category that is "close" to the image of **Top**?

There are undoubtedly other ways that one could make this question more precise; if you have a better suggestion feel free to make it.

Comment: For an example of a non-obvious property that connected subsets of a topological space satisfy, see the theorem mentioned in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/156333/86856).

Comment: Two connected components are either equal or disjoint, hence they form a *partition* of the underlying set. One could thus consider the full subcategory of pairs $(X,C_X)$ where $C_X$ is a partition of $X$. Given a partition $C_X$ ox $X$ the system of all unions $\bigcup M$ with $M\subseteq C_X$ is then a topology so that the elements of $C_X$ are the connected components.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth: The collection of all connected sets contains far more information than just the partition into connected components, because not every subset of a component is still connected.

Comment: Couldn't we take as connected space, any connected groupoid? That is, any groupoid $G$ such that for all $x$,$y$ in $Obj(G)$, $Arr(x,y)$ is  non empty?

A "connected" map will then by any functor from connected groupoids. (One could say that this captures the notion of path-connectedness, but is the distinction really relevant? :<)

Comment: With such definition, because a functor preserves isomorphisms, it is automatic that any functor from the (disjoint) sum of connected groupoids to another (disjoint) sum of connected groupoids sends connected components to connected components (that is, connected groupoids to connected groupoids).

Comment: In particular, a path in such a space $G$ could be defined as a functor from any "ordinal" categories to $G$.That is, a path is nothing else than a diagram of type $* \rightarrow *' \rightarrow *'' \rightarrow .... \rightarrow *^x$ in $G$. Clearly, for any path $f$ there exists an opposite path $-f$ (the opposite one), there is associativity by concatenation of diagrams, and identity path, so we can form a category whose objects are the objects of $G$ and arrows the paths defined previously. Such category could be called the foundamental groupoid of connected groupoids? :<

Comment: Do you want the empty set to be connected? :-) [It may seem a trivial point, but ruling it out might aid in getting a smooth axiomatics.]

Comment: You're right. I don't know if there exists a characterization of $[0,r]$ as a poset category, but I guess you could even define pathes of length $r$ in $G$ as functors from $[0,r]$ to $G$. Moreover, if $0$ is the trivial category, and $\{0,1\}$ seen as a discrete category, what would be the pushout of $[0,1] \leftarrow \{0,1\} \rightarrow {0}$ in Cat? Do we obtain something that "looks like" $S^1$ but as a category? If yes, could we also define some cone and suspension functor, in order to define  higher dimensional pathes?

Comment: Without looking at the way you've made the question precise, my immediate reaction to the question as it's first phrased is "equivalence relations." Is there more to say than this?

Comment: Possibly silly question: have you considered "$X$ is connected" to mean that if $X \cong Y \amalg Z$ then $Y$ or $Z$ is initial?

Comment: @ToddTrimble - I generally do not consider the empty set to be connected, but I suppose I'm willing to be flexible if necessary.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan can you explain in what way "equivalence relations" answers the question?

Comment: @sure, I'm having trouble putting together your sequence of comments into a coherent picture.  Maybe you could write up your proposal coherently and post it as an answer?

Comment: @Hurkyl I'm using the standard topological definition of "connected".

Comment: The notion of "separoid" may be related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separoid "Given a topological space, we can define a separoid saying that two subsets are separated if there exist two disjoint open sets which contains them (one for each of them)." But possibly it captures something slightly different from what you're looking for; I haven't thought about it.

Comment: @Mike: In **Top**, the definition I gave *is* the standard topological definition; (the images of) $Y$ and $Z$ are disjoint clopen subsets of $Y \amalg Z$, and if $U$ and $V$ are disjoint clopen subsets of $X$ with $U \cup V = X$, then $X \cong U \amalg V$.

Comment: @Hurkyl Sorry, what I meant was, what was your point in rephrasing the definition that way?

Comment: @Mike: It generalizes easily. The question seemed a bit complicated and it wasn't obvious to me what your actual goal was, so I wanted to do a quick check to see if you've already thought about the simple thing.

Comment: @Hurkyl What does it generalize, and to what?

Comment: @TobiasFritz that's different from the specific question I asked in my second paragraph, but I might still consider it an answer to my third paragraph.  I guess in a separoid you can define a subset to be "connected" if it is not the union of two nonempty separated subsets, and any morphism of separoids will preserve those?  The axioms of a separoid do seem extremely minimal, though, so they probably aren't very close to the image of **Top**.

Comment: @MikeShulman: yes, I strongly agree about the minimality of the separoid axioms! It feels like they're missing something important...

Comment: @MikeShulman: nothing interesting, I was just reinventing what is apparently already well known. I was proposing to take groupoids as the standard definition of spaces with many connected components, and functors between them as "connected maps".

Comment: @Mike: maybe I don't understand the question. On a topological space, there's an equivalence relation called "being in the same connected component." Anything one might want to say about connectedness is contained in the data of this equivalence relation. (Again, I don't understand what your precisification has to do with the question as it is stated in the first paragraph, so I don't think I understand what you're actually looking for.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I don't agree that "anything one might want to say about connectedness" is contained in that equivalence relation.  See Eric's comment above: there are connected subsets that are not components, and subsets of connected components that are not connected; and just knowing which sets are the connected components doesn't tell you anything about those sets.

Comment: @Mike: of course any subspace also has a "same connected component" equivalence relation. Can you be more specific about what sorts of things you'd like to be able to say / prove using "abstract connectedness"?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan - So are you suggesting that a "connectedness space" would be a set together with an equivalence relation on all of its subsets?  There would then presumably have to be some axioms relating those equivalence relations to each other...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There seems to be some literature on this already: this [paper](http://www.math.shimane-u.ac.jp/memoir/39/D.Buhagiar.pdf) introduces the notion of a "connective space", i.e., a set equipped with a "connectology", and develops some theory. There was some related Mathematics Stackexchange discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187145/strengthening-of-a-kuratowskis-theorem-about-connected-sets?lq=1) which connects up with the nontrivial property mentioned by Eric Wofsey in a comment below the question.

Comment: Such literature actually goes back quite a few years. I remember once reading A. D. Wallace's [*Separation spaces*](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=4756) (1941): "The paper gives a set of axioms sufficient to construct a theory of connectivity of sets in terms of a new undefined concept X|Y, which may be read "X is separated from Y"."

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Here is an ad hoc attempt. A connectivity space is an ordered pair $\ \mathbf X:=(X\ \mathcal C)\ $ such that the following two axioms hold:

1. $\ \left(A\ne\emptyset\ne B\,\ \wedge\ \,A\ B\in\mathcal C\right)\\ \quad \Rightarrow\quad \left( A\cup B\in \mathcal C\ \ \Leftrightarrow\quad\exists_{x\in A\cup B} \left(A\cup\{x\}\in\mathcal C\ \ \wedge\ \ B\cup\{x\}\in \mathcal C\right)\ \right) $
2. $\ \forall_{x\ y\,\in\,A}\ \exists_{S\in\mathcal C}\ (x\ y\in S\ \ \wedge\ \ S\subseteq A)\quad\Rightarrow\quad A\in \mathcal C$

for every $\ A\ B\ \subseteq X.\ $ Next, given connectivity spaces $\ \mathbf X:=(X\ \mathcal C)\ $ and $\ \mathbf Y:=(Y\ \mathcal D),\ $ A connectivity map (or connectivity morphism) is any function $\ f:X\rightarrow Y\ $ such that $\ \forall_{A\in\mathcal C}\ f(A)\in\mathcal D.$

Given a topological space $\ \mathbf X:=(X\ T),\ $ we get the induced connectivity space $\ \mathbf X_c := (X\ \mathcal C_T),\ $ where $\ C_T\ $ is the family of all connected subsets of $\ \mathbf X$. Thus every continuous map between two topological spaces is a connectivity map between the induced connectivity spaces.

Do not expect that there is a very close relation between continuous maps and connectivity maps. But the relation between them should be interesting (a source of new MO-questions :-) ).

> **REMARK**   It follows from the above definition (two axioms) that $\ \emptyset\in\mathcal C.\ $ (*Thank you Eric for this point*).

**EXAMPLE**   An intersection $\ \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n\ $of a monotone sequence of closed connected subspaces $\ A_n\ $ doesn't have to be connected. For instance, consider the following subspaces of $\ \mathbb R^2$:

$$A_n\ :=\ \mathbb R^2\setminus (-1;1)\times(-n;n)$$

for $\ n=1\ 2\ \ldots$

Of course a small modification will give a similar example for open connected subsets $\ B_n,\ $ say:

$$B_n\ :=\ \mathbb R^2\setminus \{0\}\times[-n;n]$$

> A point-free definition:

A connectivity structure $\ \mathcal C\ $ in set $\ X,\ $ with $\ \mathcal C_0:=\mathcal C\setminus \{\emptyset\},\ $ is defined by the following 3 axioms:

- $\forall_{A\ B\,\in\,\mathcal C_0}\ \left(A\cup B\in\mathcal C_0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad\exists_{S\in\mathcal C_0}\left(S\subseteq A\cup B\ \ \wedge\ \ A\cup S\in \mathcal C_0\ \ \wedge\ \ B\cup S\in\mathcal C_0\right)\ \right)$
- $\forall_{R\ S\,\in\,\mathcal C_0}\, \left(\left(R\cup S\,\subseteq\, A\right)\ \Rightarrow\ \exists_{Q\in\mathcal C_0}\ R\cup S\subseteq Q\subseteq A\ \right)\quad\Rightarrow\quad A\in\mathcal C_0$
- $\emptyset\,\in\,\mathcal C$

for every $\ A\ B\,\in\,X$.

> A categorical definition

**TERMINOLOGY**   A category $\ \mathbf C\ $ is called *vague* $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\,\ \forall_{X\ Y\,\in\,Obj(\mathbf C)}\ |\,MOR(X\ Y)\,|\ \le\ 1$

**EXAMPLE**   The category of all sets and of the **identity** embeddings is vague.

**DEFINITION 1  of a (connected) union**   Let category $\ \mathbf C\ $ be vague. An object $\ C\ $ of objects $\ A\ B\ $ is called a *union* $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ $ two conditions hold:

- $\ \exists_{S\,\in\,Obj(\mathbf C)}\\ \ \quad |\,MOR(S\ A)\,|\ =\ |\,MOR(S\ B)\,|\ =\ |\,MOR(A\ C)\,|\ =\ |\,MOR(B\ C\,|\ =\ 1$
- whenever $\ D\ $ is like $\ C\ $ above then $\ |\,MOR(C\ D)\,|\ =\ 1$.

Thus with every vague category $\ \mathbf C\ $we associate a u-graph, where two objects $\ A\ B\ $ are connected (i.e. form an edge of the connectivity graph) $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ $ there exists a union of $\ A\ $ and $\ B.$

**DEFINITION 2  of merger**   Let category $\ \mathbf C\ $ be vague. Objects $\ A\ B\ $ *merge* into an object $\ C\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ $ two conditions hold:

- $\ |\,MOR(A\ C)\,|\ =\ |\,MOR(B\ C)\,|\ =\ 1$
- whenever $\ D\ $ is like $\ C\ $ above, then $\ |\,|MOR(C\ D)\,|\ =\ 1$

With every vague category $\ \mathbf C\ $ we associate the merging graph of objects of $\ C\ $, where two objects form an edge $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ $ if they merge.

> **DEFINITION 3  of a connectivity category:**

A category $\ \mathbf C\ $ is a connectivity graph $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ $ it satisfies the following four axioms:

1. $\ \mathbf C\ $ is vague;
2. every union of objects of $\ \mathbf C\ $ is a merger;
3. if $\ A\ B\ $ merge, and if $\ |\,MOR(A\ A')\,|\ 1\ $ then $\ A'\ $ and $\ B\ $ merge too;
4. if $\ \mathbf D\ $ is a non-empty family of objects such that the full induced merger subgraph  $\ \mathbf D\ $ is connected then there exists an object $\ C\ $ which is a merger of $\ \mathbf D,\ $ meaning that the following two conditions hold:

   - $\ \forall_{A\in\mathbf D}\ \ |\,MOR(A\ C)\,|\ =\ 1$
   - whenever $\ D\ $ is like $\ C\ $ then $\ \,MOR(C\ D)\,|\ =\ 1$

INTERPRETATION: The objects of a connectivity category play the role of non-empty connected spaces.

> Back to topology:

In the case of a topological space $\ \mathbf X,\ $ the category $\ \mathbf C :=\mathbf C_{\mathbf X}\ $ consists of the non-empty connected subsets of $\ \mathbf X,\ $ and of the identity embeddings.

Comment: I was just about to fix this nasty typo. Thank you Eric!

Comment: Note that these axioms do not imply singletons are connected, nor do they rule out having only singletons and the whole space being connected (which is impossible for topological spaces with more than two points by [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153376/antisymmetry-among-cut-points/156333#156333)).

Comment: I always wondered what would happen if we took as **definition** of continuity, something like that: A function $f : A \rightarrow B$ is continuous iff its graph (or even its closure with product topology) $\Gamma(f)$ is connected in $A\times B$. This, in my opinion, captures the notion of continuity of "walking" of any ball of radius $\epsilon$, you stay inside your space (in the sense of metric space).

Comment: @EricWofsey -- thank you again; I fixed the issue of the empty set. (Perhaps there are more things to fix),

Comment: @sure -- What about a disconnected $\ A\ $ ?

Comment: @sure. This is a nice try, but it does not work. It is true that a function from $\mathbf R$ to itself is continuous if and only if its graph is closed and connected. However, I remember that there are counterexamples for functions from $\mathbf R^2$ to $\mathbf R$.

Comment: @ACL: no there are no such obvious links. For example, the topologist sin curve is not at all continuous at 0, yet its graph is connected! Oh sorry, you said closed too

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński: I guess you could take the topological sum to make sense of this, that is, connectivity "by part"?

Comment: @sure. I had forgotten the precision “closed and connected“; I edited the comment.

Comment: An equivalent restatement of (2) (in the presence of (1)) that is perhaps more natural and also correctly handles the empty set is that a directed union of connected sets is connected.

Comment: @sure -- a non-continuous map from a circle to $\ \mathbb R\ $ or (even to the circle) may still have a connected graph. Connected graph is not a local property. But, as we saw, even a local connectedness of a graph doesn't force continuity.

Comment: @EricWofsey -- I considered both (basically equivalent) versions. I felt that the 2-point version was somewhat simpler. I remembered a similar situation for a (generalized) convex structure--analogous two conditions occur there too (but the 2-point condition is stronger in the convex case).

Comment: A simple way how to handle the empty set correctly is to drop the assumption $A\ne\emptyset\ne B$ from axiom 1.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek -- you must be right, thank you; I am in poor shape, and it's hard for me to take care of pests like the empty set. If axiom 1 is not in error then hopefully I'd like to come back to it a bit later too make thing smoother.

Comment: Sorry to hear you’re unwell. Actually, I forgot to fix axiom 2 accordingly; one would need to either add the assumption $A\ne\emptyset$ there, or use Eric Wofsey’s suggestion.

Comment: This is very interesting, although it will take me some time to digest it.  Three comments/questions for now: (1) As I said to Todd, I think the empty set should not be connected.  (2) Can you say anything about where these axioms came from?  (3) One possible downside of these axioms is that they aren't clearly "closure conditions", which means it's not obvious that the category of connectivity spaces will have initial and terminal structures, or even limits and colimits.  Does it?

Comment: Mike, about your (1) above, what would be your reason to let $\ \emptyset\ $ be disconnected? About (2), could you be a bit more specific? About (3), please, I'll try to say something later (if I can :-).

Comment: (1) the same reasons that 1 is not a prime number.  For instance, if $\emptyset$ is connected then the decomposition of a space into connected components is not unique since you can always add more copies of $\emptyset$.  (2) What motivated you to write down these axioms?  How did you think of them?

Comment: Mike, nice, yes, prime numbers :-)

Comment: Perhaps the empty set should be considered neither connected nor disconnected.

Answer (score 2):

Let me answer as to how well the connected subspaces of a space determine the topology. I claim that for a large class of spaces, the collection of all connected subsets of the space determines the topology on $X$. However, the functions between nice connected spaces that map connected sets to connected sets are generally not continuous.

The following lemma states that the closure of a connected subspace of a regular space $X$ is determined by the collection of all connected subspaces of $X$. In particular, the closed connected subspaces of a regular space $X$ are determined by the collection of all the connected subspaces of $X$.

$\mathbf{Lemma}$ Suppose that $X$ is a regular space and $A\subseteq X$ is a connected subset. Then $\{a\}\cup A$ is connected if and only if $a\in\overline{A}$.
Furthermore, if $A\subseteq B\subseteq X$, then $B\subseteq\overline{A}$ if and only if whenever $A\subseteq C\subseteq B$ then $\overline{C}$ is connected.

The proof of the above lemma is straightforward.

We shall say that a point $x$ is a connected space $X$ is a nbd-cut-point if there is some open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that whenever $V$ is an open set with $x\in V\subseteq U$, then $X\setminus V$ is not connected. Then it is easy to show that a connected space $X$ has no nbd-cut-points if and only if every closed subspace of $X$ is the intersection of connected closed subspaces of $X$. I should also mention that I made up the notion of a nbd-cut-point in order to answer this question, but the notion of a nbd-cut-point is closely related to the notion of a cut-point since every cut point is a nbd-cut-point.

$\mathbf{Proposition}$ Suppose that $X,Y$ are connected regular spaces with no nbd-cut points. If there is a bijection $f:X\rightarrow Y$ so that if $C\subseteq X$ then $C$ is connected if and only if $f[C]$ is connected, then $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic.

However, I must mention that even for connected regular spaces with no nbd-cut-points, there are non-continuous maps where the image of a connected space is connected. For example, define an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}$ where $x\simeq y$ iff $x-y\in\mathbb{Q}$. Then there is a surjective function $f:\mathbb{R}/\simeq\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$ since $|\mathbb{R}/\simeq|=|\mathbb{R}^{2}|$. Define a mapping $g:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$ by letting $g(x,y)=f([x])$ and define $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$ by letting $h(x)=f([x])$. Then $h[U]=\mathbb{R}^{2}$ for each nonempty open set $U$. I claim that $g$ maps connected subsets to connected subsets. Let $\pi_{1},\pi_{2}:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be the projection maps where $\pi_{1}(x,y)=x,\pi_{2}(x,y)=y$. Suppose that $C\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is connected. Then $\pi_{1}[C]$ is also connected, so $\pi_{1}[C]$ is either a singleton or an interval. If $\pi_{1}[C]$ is a singleton, then $g[C]$ is a singleton in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. However, if $\pi_{1}[C]$ is an interval, then $g[C]=\mathbb{R}^{2}$. In either case, the function $g$ maps connected sets to connected sets, but the function $g$ is very far from being continuous. It therefore seems as if the notion of continuity cannot be described in terms of connectedness unless one describes the open or closed sets in terms of connectedness and directly translates the notion of continuity into a notion of a connected mapping.

Answer (score 1):

A relevant idea by @sure was relegated (by her/him-self!) to comments. Let me give it justice here. Actually, I'll provide a counter-example:

**THEOREM**   There exists a **non-continuous** map $\ f : X\ \rightarrow Y\ $ of a metric 1-dimensional compact **connected** space $\ X\ $ into a metric 1-dimensional separable complete space $\ Y\ $ such that the graph $\ G(f)\subseteq X\times Y\ $ is a **closed connected** subset.

**PROOF**   Let $\ X:=S^1\ $ be the unit circle in the complex plane, with center $\ 0.\ $ Let $\ Y:=\mathbb R.\ $ Define

$$\forall_{t\,:\, 0\le t< 2\cdot\pi}\ \ f\left(e^{\imath\cdot t}\right)\ :=\ \tan\left(\frac t4\right)$$

That's it, **END of Proof**.

Answer (score 0):

Its only a trivial observation, but too long for a comment:

We represent a topological space in terms of closet's $(X, \tau)$, then $\tau \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ (where $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is the set of part's of $X$) and $\tau$ is closed for finite unions, and general intersection, $X\in\tau$ and  $\emptyset=\bigcap \tau$.

I define a connect structure as a ordered couple $(X, \chi)$ where $\chi\subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ have mutually disjoint elements and $X=\bigcup \chi$, a morphism of connect structures $f: (X_1, \chi_1)\to (X_2, \chi_2)$ is a map of set's $f: X_1\to X_2$ such that $\forall C_1\in \chi_1\  \exists C_2\in \chi_2: f(C_1)\subset C_2$.

Of course we have a  (I seem a topological) functor $F$ from the topological spaces to connected structures, where $F(X, \tau)$ is $(X, \chi)$ with $\chi$ the sets of topological connect component. We have also that $\chi$ is the minimum of the set of families $\mathcal{A}\subset \tau$ with  mutually disjoint elements, and $X=\bigcup \mathcal{A}$, ordered as $\mathcal{A}\leq \mathcal{B}$ if $\forall A\in \mathcal{A}\ \exists B\in \mathcal{B}: A\subset B$.  This definition don't use "points" may be can be generalized (by some additional hypothesis) to locales (in term of closed sublocales) but I dont know.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing something similar to what  Jochen proposed in a comment.  But I definitely want to consider connected subsets that are not *components*.